# How to customize the keyboard with react native

Tags: ios, react-native, uikeyboard

How can I customize a keyboard similar to the one in the screenshot below with a custom toolbar above it? Is there a library that can implement it?

[image: keyboard]

Comment: Look into [InputAccessoryView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/inputaccessoryview).
Also found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-accessory) and [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@flyerhq/react-native-keyboard-accessory-view) which may be useful.

Comment: OK, thank you. I'll see it